# Primary links background not visible by non-admins

Tags: 7, theming

I have styled my primary links with a background and it all works out just fine. Except for when I log out, the background disappears.
So it looks like the anonymous user doesn't have permissions to see the background (which I would fine strange...)

Is this a known issue and if so, what can I do about this?

Comment: There's no such thing as Drupal CSS permissions; this is not a known issue.  (If the primary links themselves disappear, that could be a permissions issue, but not just the background.)  Did you style the admin theme by mistake instead of the theme users actually see?  Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: You'll need to post your CSS  if you want an  informed answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the correct classes? E.g. when you use the .logged-in class in your CSS, the style will not be used when not logged in.

Comment: It was indeed the classes... I figured it out while debugging. Thanks for your tip!